# Determining Consecutive Days Using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, data-science

I have a Pandas DataFrame that looks something like this:

```
                                                       activity_id                            start                              end type  ...                                        site  heart_rate  grp_idx        date
user_id                                                                                                                                    ...
72xyy89c74cc57178e02f103187ad579  dcb12345678b5c8e84cf2931b1a553cb 2015-09-12 00:40:33.171000+00:00 2015-09-12 00:53:33.171000+00:00  run  ...  data\dcb12345678b5c8e84cf2931b1a553cb.json         NaN  2015-37  2015-09-12
```

The DataFrame has already been filtered such that all user_id is the same.

The dtypes are:

```
activity_id                 object
start          datetime64[ns, UTC]
end            datetime64[ns, UTC]
type                        object
distance                   float64
steps                      float64
speed                      float64
pace                       float64
calories                   float64
ascent                     float64
descent                    float64
site                        object
heart_rate                 float64
grp_idx                     object
date                        object
```

I need to determine if there are x (e.g. 4) consecutive days in a row and find the number of times that has occurred. For example:

```
2015-09-12
2015-09-13
2015-09-14
2015-09-15
2015-09-16
2015-09-17
2015-09-18
2015-09-19
```

Would count as two.

I have tried using groupby, e.g.:

```
s = repeat_runner_df.groupby('user_id').start.diff().dt.days.fillna(1).cumsum()
repeat_runner_df.groupby(['user_id', s]).filter(lambda x: len(x) < 3)
print(repeat_runner_df)
```

but that has gotten me nowhere and neither has my Google skills. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
c7e962db02da12345f02fe3d8a86c99d          2018-04-08 03:16:06+00:00        2018-04-08 03:41:30+00:00  run  ...           NaN  2018-14  2018-04-08
c7e962db02da12345f02fe3d8a86c99d          2018-04-09 17:21:37+00:00        2018-04-09 18:27:17+00:00  run  ...           NaN  2018-14  2018-04-09
c7e962db02da12345f02fe3d8a86c99d          2018-04-10 19:05:39+00:00        2018-04-10 19:38:32+00:00  run  ...           NaN  2018-15  2018-04-10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
count = df.groupby(df.start.diff().ne(pd.Timedelta(days=1)).cumsum()).apply(len).ge(4).sum()
```

Output:

```
>>> count
3
```

Comment: I tried this and modified to


```
count = df.groupby(df.start.diff().ne(pd.Timedelta(days=1)).cumsum()).apply(len).ge(3).sum()
```


But on a sample where I can see all the lines of data and there are three consecutive days in a row, the value of count is 0.

Comment: The DataFrame has already been filtered such that all user_id is the same.

Comment: Will you please share that sample, in your question? I'm probably misunderstanding some nuanced detail.

Comment: I added some sample data at the end, where the far left column is user_id, the next colum is start, the next column is end, etc. As you can see, if I change ge(4) to ge(3), it should at least return a count of 1, but instead returns 0.

Comment: So, when you use diff(), it's the difference between the current date and the previous date, which is why this is not working. The date before 2014-04-08 is 2014-04-06, which is 2+ days and so 2014-04-08 gets excluded in that groupby.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what youre looking for:

```
consecutive = 4
(df.groupby(['user_id',df.groupby('user_id')['start']
             .transform(lambda x: x.diff().dt.days.ne(1).cumsum())])['user_id']
 .cumcount().add(1).eq(consecutive).sum())
```

Comment: I keep getting the following error:

KeyError: 'Column not found: user_id'

Comment: The DataFrame has already been filtered such that all user_id is the same.

Comment: For the first `groupby`, change `'user_id'` to `level=0` (`.groupby(level=0)`), and the for the second `groupby`, change `['user_id', s]` to `pd.Grouper(s, level=0)` (`.groupby(pd.Grouper(s, level=0))`).

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to modify the code. Just tried and getting lots of red lines :/

Comment: Yeah, an explanation of what it does how it does would help for debugging

Comment: @Neither aye, this has become enormously frustrating.